# Drupal data not adopting an orphan table - Apparently this is a table prefix issue (not sure what that means)?

Tags: mysql, drupal, forms, drupal-views, drupal-forms

I'm working my way through the Webform MySQL/Data solution http://nodeone.se/blogg/finally-webform-submission-data-in-views. All the required modules are installed, everything looks fine. However, when I go to admin/build/data/adopt and select the webform table I've created, it doesn't get added to the available tables at admin/build/data.

If I go back to admin/content/webform/mysql and deselect/reselect the webform, I get error messages from Data:

Data module was unable to drop view (table name)

Data module was unable to adopt view (table name)

There's not much to go on here. Any ideas what could be keeping Data from adopting/dropping these tables?

This is similar issue to that a user had here http://drupal.org/node/1040054#comment-4530296. Apparently, it's a table prefix issue. What does this mean and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably a database permission. The "user", used by Drupal for accessing the database has not enough permissions and is not allowed to create or delete views.

You can check this by running the SQL query under the user that Drupal connects with to the database:

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS SELECT * FROM node WHERE status = 1
DROP VIEW testview
```

You will most probably get an error then.

In that case, you should grant the user the permissions to CREATE, UPDATE and DROP views:

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW, DROP, UPDATE ON drupal_db.* TO 'the_user'@'localhost';
```